# Performance of JSF h:InputHidden fields with attribute readonly=true

Tags: jsf

I would assume that hidden input fields defined as read-only such as

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.field}" readonly="true" id="field" />
```

are faster than fields defined with `readonly="false"` (or with the readonly attribute ommited altogether), but I couldn't find any information on this topic.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated, as I have several pages with large number of h:inputHidden fields that are read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h:inputHidden`  doesn't have attribute `readonly`. See this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputHidden.html)

But `h:inputText` does have that attribute `readonly`.
I don't think Perfomance(Faster) is the reason for using the `readonly="true"`.  [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html)

> Flag indicating that this component will prohibit changes by the user.

Primefaces creator Cagatay Civici comented in forum that:

> JSF and PrimeFaces do not process values when inputs are disabled or
>   readOnly for security purposes. So even a hacker enables the input and
>   submits the form, JSF-PrimeFaces checks the component. So it is
>   standard behavior. You need to enable it on server side.